# unordered_map priority_queue comparator

Tags: c++, comparator, priority-queue

I have a struct that consists of a name and an age. What I would like is to have an unordered_map that takes a strings as its keys and then either a map or a priority_queue that then stores the age given that string:
I have a struct that contains name and age. I would like to use unordered_map to take string name as key, priority_queue (min heap) stores Cats sorted by age. I have problem writing comparator.

Can someone help me with my comparator (`comp` below)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

struct Cat{
    string name;
    int age;
    Cat(string nm, int a) : name(nm), age(a) {}
};

auto comp = [] (const Cat &a, const Cat &b) {
    return a.age > b.age;
};

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    unordered_map<string, priority_queue<Cat,vector<Cat>, decltype(comp)> mp;
    Cat c = new Cat("Bobby", 1); 
    mp[c.name].push(c);
    return 0;
}
```

It is working now. See below for details. :)

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

class Cat{
    public:
    string name;
    int age;
    Cat(string nm, int a) : name(nm), age(a) {}
};

//auto comp = [] (const Cat &a, const Cat &b) { return a.age > b.age; };

class comp

{public:
    bool operator() (Cat const &a, Cat const &b) { return a.age < b.age; }
};

int main()
{
    priority_queue<Cat,vector<Cat>,  comp> q ;
    unordered_map<string, priority_queue<Cat,vector<Cat>,   comp  > >mp  ;
    Cat c("Bobby", 1);
    Cat* pt = new Cat("Bobby", 3);
    Cat d("Bobby", 2); 
    mp[pt->name].push(*pt);
    mp[d.name].push(d);
    mp[c.name].push(c);
    while (!mp["Bobby"].empty()) {
        Cat t = mp["Bobby"].top();
        cout << "name = " << t.name << " age = " << t.age << endl;
        mp["Bobby"].pop();
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you defined `comp`?

Comment: You need two different comparators - one for the priority queue, and a different one for the unordered map.

Comment: @Archinde updated!

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm unordered_map is a hashmap, right? how to add a different comparator ?

Comment: Is the `name` stored in `Cat` the same as the `string` used as the key in the map?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm yes, Cat c = new Cat("Bobby", 1); mp[c.name].push(c);

Answer (score 0):

In case you still cares about this one. I just spent some time on this one, when you are using auto keyword on the lambda compare, it's deducing the type of the "compare" variable as boolean. Instead you want to declare the lambda as `function<bool(int,int)>` such that the type passed in the priority_queue template is a function type (or callable object) instead of a plain variable.